# nothrowのようなそれ自体機能をもたないが、指定することで別の演算子やクラスに振るまいを変更させるためのオブジェクトを一般的になんと言いますが？

Tags: c++

タイトルの通りですが、ズバリ、 xxxオブジェクトのxxxを知りたく質問しています。

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`std::nothrow`オブジェクトと`std::nothrow_t`型](http://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/new/nothrow_t.html)のことであれば、一般に「タグ(tag)」オブジェクト／型と呼ばれます。

C++標準ライブラリでは`std::nothrow`の他にも、[`std::piecewise_construct`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/utility/piecewise_construct_t.html)や[`std::defer_lock`](http://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/mutex/defer_lock.html)などが該当します。

オブジェクトそのものよりも、同オブジェクトを利用してオーバーロード関数選択を行う「タグ・ディスパッチ(Tag Dispatch)」の方がよく知られている気がします。

Comment: ズバリ感のある回答ありがとうございます。出典があれば助かります。(書籍やリンクなど)

Comment: 慣習的な呼び名なので出典というのも難しいですが、[Boostのドキュメント](http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#tag_dispatching)では "A **tag** is simply a class whose only purpose is to convey some property for use in tag dispatching and similar techniques." とあります。

Comment: ありがとうございました。参考にさせていただきます。

Answer (score -3):

『修飾子』でどうでしょう？

これをオブジェクトとは言わないでしょうけど。